# HTMLAnchor server click refreshing page so the expetced result is missing

Tags: web-part

I have created a simple SharePoint web part with HTMLAnchor tag with server click event handler by following the below article.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor.serverclick?view=netframework-4.7.2

Code Piece: AnchorButton.ServerClick += new System.EventHandler(this.HtmlAnchor_Click);

In the development environment (SharePoint 2013) it works fine, but when I deploy the same solution in production, when I click on this button, it is refreshing my whole page so the expected results are missing.

Is this environment related issue? How do I troubleshoot this behavior/issue.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what your "expected results" are, but a server control click will issue a full postback. If your data resides in ViewState (other server controls) then checking for IsPostBack on the Page_Load might be what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your response. On page load I am constructing some text and storing in a hidden text column on the page. When this button is clicked, I am exporting that content to Excel file using this code, HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("stringvalue");. Instead of prompting to save the file, it is just refreshing the page.

Comment: Are you checking for IsPostBack? A full reload is going to erase that hidden field from ViewState.